# How to know where the pdb files is looking for source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, pdb-files

I have an external `dll` and a `pdb` file from `C#` code. I have the source code downloaded on my computer. In Visual Studio, under `modules`, `Symbol status` is: `Symbol loaded` for that specific dll. But `User code` is: `N/A`.

And I can't step into the functions in that dll. How do I know where to put the source code so the `pdb` finds it? Is the pdb looking the `C#` source file in a specific directory and is there a way to find out where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool called `SrcTool.exe` that is installed with the WinSDK. `Srctool.exe` utility lists all files indexed within the .pdb file.

`SrcTool.exe -r filename.pdb` will print the source file paths.